Center a container in flutter and make it scrollable when keyboard is visible
I have a screen in which I have a container with fixed width but unconstrained height. The contents of the container are hidden by the keyboard popup. I want to make the container scrollable or in focus when the keyboard popup is shown. Following is my code:
Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.green, // Set the background color of the app
      body: Center(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Container(
            width: 480,
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
            color: Colors.white, // Set the background color of the container
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                TextField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Field 1'),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 16.0), // Add spacing between fields
                TextField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Field 2'),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 16.0),
                TextField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Field 3'),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 16.0),
                TextField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Field 4'),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 16.0),
                TextField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Field 5'),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );

It only happens when the phone is in landscape view and I click on a textfield that brings the keyboard popup. I tried chatgtp and gemini but they both give the same answers that do not work. Kindly help. Currently it looks like this
Current issue

I have tried your given code in landscape view, and I able to scroll the container very well while keyboard is open.

The container scrolls until the top of the container touches the top of the screen. If the container height is greater than the screen height, you will see the issue

Try to give bottom padding to SingleChildScrollView as your requirement.

No it did not work. I noticed something. When i press hot reload, the container moves above the keyboard and stays there. When i hide the keyboard and press hot reload again, the container comes back to the center of the screen

To make your container scrollable when the keyboard is displayed, you can use SingleChildScrollView in the body of a scaffold and ensure that your TextFields are handled correctly when the keyboard appears. You can also use MediaQuery to adjust the padding of SingleChildScrollView to account for the keyboard.
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.green, // Set the background color of the app
      body: Center(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom),
          child: Container(
            width: 480,
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
            color: Colors.white, // Set the background color of the container
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                TextField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Field 1'),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 16.0), // Add spacing between fields
                TextField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Field 2'),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 16.0),
                TextField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Field 3'),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 16.0),
                TextField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Field 4'),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 16.0),
                TextField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Field 5'),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}







This is what chat gpt gave me as solution and it did not work  :(
Try running it on landscape view

The code works perfectly in landscape mode. And Im aware that using AI-generated code on StackOverflow can result in a ban.

Put your Container widget in a Column. Normally, I use SingleChildScrollView and Column together.
Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.green, // Set the background color of the app
      body: Center(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          padding: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets,
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: [
              Container(
                width: 480,
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                color: Colors.white, // Set the background color of the container
                child: const Column(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    TextField(
                      decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Field 1'),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 16.0), // Add spacing between fields
                    TextField(
                      decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Field 2'),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 16.0),
                    TextField(
                      decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Field 3'),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 16.0),
                    TextField(
                      decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Field 4'),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 16.0),
                    TextField(
                      decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Field 5'),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  



Your solution did not work for me :(

Did you copy the code I provided? The screenshot is using that code

Yes i tried your code. The last text field is always hidden under the keyboard. However, I noticed that if i press hot reload, it moved above the keyboard and stays there until I hide the keyboard and press hot reload again

You can try adding this to the SingleChildScrollView:           padding: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets,
